# How to access Galaxy S5 heart rate sensor?

Tags: java, android, heartbeat, samsung-mobile-sdk

In the [Samsung's programming guide](http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/SHealth_SDK_Package_ProgrammingGuide_2_Bio_Physiology_eng_v1.pdf) (pages 77 - 81) there is a reference on how to set and get the heart rate information using the S Health Service SDK. However, I was looking to directly access the Galaxy S5's heart rate sensor, the same way you are able to access the accelerometer, gyroscope, light sensor, among other sensors.
I found [this example for the samsung gear live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664217/get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live), but I cannot find any example for Galaxy S5.

Is it possible to directly access the Galaxy S5's heart rate sensor? Does anyone has a code example on how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: This may help you: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=269251

Comment: Thank you your answer. I've checked that forum thread but it only provides information on how to get heart rate info from the S Health Service SDK. I need to directly access the heart rate sensor in real time the same way you are able to do it using the accelerometer, gyroscope, light sensor, among other sensors.

Comment: What output do you get with the code in the question you linked? (The one that shows all sensors.) And did you include the `BODY_SENSORS` permission as suggested?

Comment: I don't have a galaxy s5. I'm just wondering if the same code used for the galaxy gear can be used to access the galaxy s5 heart rate sensor as well? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you expect it to _not_ work the same?

Comment: Since they are different devices, I'm wondering if the code works the same way for both. :S Have you tried the code in the Galaxy S5? I would like to be certain of it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't have one either. I'd recommend getting one (or borrowing a friend's, for example) if you want to create S5-specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get raw heart rate monitor data from Samsung Galaxy S5.

Sensors Extension SDK is required to get raw data from sensors not supported by Google Android and [this page](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/sensor-extension) states that:

Sensor Extension SDK has the following restrictions:

- HRM Sensor IR/RED Signal

  - Devices with Android 5.0 (Lollipop API level 21) or higher is required.
  - **Galaxy S5** and Galaxy S5mini are **excluded**.
  - Only supported by Samsung device with HRM sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(65562)` to get direct access to the HRM sensor.

Answer (score 1):

To access and enable infra red light:

1. Use at Manifest

   uses permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
2. implement SensorEventListener at Activity
3. To enable red infrared light use code:

   ```
    public void enableHeartRate(){

       SensorManager mSensorManager = ((SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
       Sensor mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);

       mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   }

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

       if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
           String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];

           Log.d(TAG, msg);
       }else{
           Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

   }
   ```
4. Check Log for results
   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has released an SDK called SensorExtension. You must apply for it and they will send you an email with the zip file.

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#sensor-extension

Answer (score 0):

```
SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE)
```

works well.

**But**

> This sensor requires permission android.permission.BODY_SENSORS. It
>   will not be returned by SensorManager.getSensorsList nor
>   SensorManager.getDefaultSensor if the application doesn't have this
>   permission.

*(from the documentation)*

So if you readers tried *getDefaultSensor* without success, this is likely to be the error.