# How can I access the heart rate sensor on my galaxy s5 using the standard apis?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, samsung-mobile

Starting from [How to access Galaxy S5 heart rate sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712968/how-to-access-galaxy-s5-heart-rate-sensor/27589629#27589629) I tried to access the S5 heart rate monitor via android API (not Samsung health APIs)

This other example, for samsung wear, https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/d23bfe583e900a4f9276 does not work on S5.

In the meanwhile I listed all the available sensors on the S5 via code and found two interesting ones:

```
65561 MAX86900
65562 HRM Sensor
```

The S5 BOM says:

> Biosensor (heart rate) – MFG: MAXIM INTEGRATED PRODUCTS INC – MPN: MAX86900 –

Using `65561` as sensor ID I get some data (and it changes if I move my finger over the sensor).

Using `65562` I cannot get call to the callback.

The other sensors I found:

```
    1 MPU6500 Acceleration Sensor
    2 AK09911C Magnetic field Sensor
   14 AK09911C Magnetic Sensor UnCalibrated
    4 MPU6500 Gyroscope Sensor
   16 MPU6500 Uncalibrated Gyroscope Sensor
    8  TMG399X Proximity Sensor
    5 TMG399X RGB Sensor
   11 MPL Rotation Vector
   15 MPL Game Rotation Vector 
   18 SAMSUNG Step Detector Sensor
   19 SAMSUNG Step Counter Sensor
   17 SAMSUNG Significant Motion Sensor
65558 Screen Orientation Sensor
    3 Orientation Sensor
    9 Gravity Sensor
   10 Linear Acceleration Sensor
```

So, is there a way to access the heart rate monitor of the Galaxy S5 using only the standard APIs?

Comment: Your question is very forum-like. This is usually a bad fit for Stack Overflow. We try to have questions with specific problems that have distinctive testable answers. Your question seem to seek general input and discussion, which is a poor fit for the Q&A format here. Otherwise an interesting question. You might want to have a look at the android section here on SE: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well the question-specific would be: How can i access the heart rate sensor on my galaxy s5 using the standard apis?Do you mean something like that?

Comment: Yes, that would be much better.

Comment: I restructured your question to better fit the format here. Your "is there any reason..." question does not fit SO style, you might want to ask that somewhere else (e.G. in the android stack site chat room)

Comment: How did you find the sensor list (with number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same question already asked: [How to access Galaxy S5 heart rate sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712968/how-to-access-galaxy-s5-heart-rate-sensor)

"Use `SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(65562)` to get direct access to the HRM sensor."
by VD63

Comment: my bad, i did not image that i need to put my finger in front of the sensor otherwise no data will be gathered!