# can Tizen O/S by Samsung read heart beats?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'd like to detect the users heart beat but im not sure if Tizen (the mobile O/S by samsung) can detect heart beats.  with samsung gear i found this SO article: [Get Heart Rate from "Sensor" Samsung Gear Live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664217/get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live) but i need it with Tizen, any ideas ?

Comment: Not directly Tizen could do, but if you can write Tizen codes, you can detect heart rate. Also on App markets, you can find heart rate apps easily to detect heart beats. A camera and a led allows you to detect heart rate if you code and program Tizen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can detect user **heart rate** with Tizen based Samsung gear devices. FYI all Samsung gear devices released till now except gear live are Tizen based.

Have a look at this link on how to monitor heart rate https://developer.tizen.org/fr/development/guides/web-application/tizen-features/system/human-activity-monitor?langredirect=1

You can use the Heart rate monitor sensor which is available on the gear.

Check this link on how to code https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html